# Use dbo.table SQL Server error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database, and I am importing a big table...
When I try to execute a stored procedure I have no success, to check I do something simple like:

```
select * from tableAT;
```

but the tableAT is marked as error (even when it appears in the Object explorer window),

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'tableAT'.
```

but if I do right click and select the icon of the table and select
`SELECT TOP 1000 ROWS`
a result is coming and the query shown is

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [1]
      ,[2], etc...
  FROM [DB_NAME].[dbo].[tableAT]
```

if I change the way I am calling the store procedure to

```
exec procedureA [DB_NAME].[dbo].[tableAT]
```

I get error as if the table does not exist?

Do you know why could this be error?
A size issue, I already incremented the database initial size files...

Comment: does the `SELECT TOP 1000...` query execute correctly?

Comment: yes, that is really strange..., the problem is when executing stored procedure, is acting as if I passes an empty table

Comment: also when I put `dbo.`   (and the available objects appear) the table I imported is not shown here...

Comment: please copy and paste your stored proc / table structure (right click, script to clipboard). It is not a size issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be logged in as admin user to select from this table. Because it is created for dbo. Or you should have proper rights

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set up your table valued parameter correctly: [here's an example](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters).